# Roundtrip IPython transform_cell

Tags: python, ipython

Consider the following example:

```py
>>> from IPython.core.inputtransformer2 import TransformerManager
>>> src = """\
... foo = !ls
... !!ls
... """
>>> TransformerManager().transform_cell(src)
"foo = get_ipython().getoutput('ls')\nget_ipython().getoutput('ls')\n"
```

Both `!ls` and `!!ls` got transformed to `get_ipython().getoutput('ls')`.

If I only saw the output of `TransformerManager().transform_cell`, would there be a way to retrieve the original source?

Is there a way to tell whether `get_ipython().get_output(<some string>)` came from `!<some string>` or `!!<some string>`?

Comment: What should `!!ls` do though?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question

Comment: What does it do? Like `!ls` prints out the current files in the directory, but what about the `!!ls` in your code?

Comment: It's valid IPython syntax - I'm not so concerned about what it does, but about round-tripping valid IPython syntax

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a closer look at how `TransformerManager` works under the hood to recognize ipython special commands:

`TransformerManager` tries to match each line to one of the following structures:

- magic assignements (`%%my ipython magic`)
- system assigns (`foo = !cmd`)
- escaped commands (`!cmd` and `!!cmd`)

## System assigns

In the case of [system assigns](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/9cbb3ba6aeba88a76da9dc73c1d1934b09cc2a63/IPython/core/inputtransformer2.py#L268), the first `!` after the `=` sign is stripped, and whatever follows is used as the argument of `get_ipython().getoutput`.

*ex:* `foo = !ls` -> `foo = get_ipython().getoutput('ls')`

## Escaped commands

In the case of so-called "[escaped commands](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/9cbb3ba6aeba88a76da9dc73c1d1934b09cc2a63/IPython/core/inputtransformer2.py#L391)", that is, system calls without assignements, a difference is made between `!cmd`, which gets translated to `get_ipython().system(cmd)` and `!!cmd`, which becomes `get_ipython().getoutput(cmd)`.

We can therefore figure out the number of exclamation marks used by using some basic regex to detect whether an assignement is present or not:

```py
import re

def get_number_exclamation_marks(transformed_line):
    """
    Takes the output of TransformerManager for one ipython line, and returns the
    number of exclamation marks used in the system call. If no system call
    is present, returns 0.
    """
    if re.search(r"= *get_ipython\(\)\.getoutput\(", transformed_line)\
    or re.search(r"get_ipython\(\)\.system\(", transformed_line):
        return 1
    if re.search(r"get_ipython\(\)\.getoutput\(", transformed_line):
        return 2
    return 0
```

NB: The case `foo=!!cmd` is not treated by the above function, as it is invalid ipython syntax.

Comment: Thanks - I would use ast-parsing to detect an assignment rather than regex, but the idea seems right. Thanks! Are you sure that those are the only cases to consider?

Comment: Pretty sure, yes :) 
I linked the relevant parts of the ipython source code in the inital answer if you want to double-check, but it's straightforward enough that I'm not too worried about having missed any edge cases.